# Displaying personalized Social media ads using Sitecore

Tags: marketing-definitions

Just wanted to know whether ads can be displayed in social media channels from Sitecore? We came across "Komfo" module which has helped in achieving it, but it looks like it was only available for older Sitecore versions i.e. version 8. Is there any alternative that is available now?

Basically, I want to know how I can display a targeted ad to an individual in any social media channel using the latest version of Sitecore, provided it is possible **out of the box** in Sitecore. Thanks!